# Bootstrap Doesn't work properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement an admin panel to my bootstrap template. But when i change slider elements to a loop (get elements from DB and echo them in form of the skeleton li element, function echoes with no problem), the theme become broken. I didn't see anything wrong about code, it's the same as html one.

links:
proper one: http://server.tartismaliyiz.com/emlak/

broken one: http://server.tartismaliyiz.com/royalEmlak

static html li element:

```
<li>
        <div class="shad">
            <div class="mask">
                <div class="box-detail">
                    <h3>Royal Gayrimenkul</h3>
                    <div class="box-detail-item">
                        <div class="item-price pull-left">$278.7800</div>
                        <a hrf="#" class="item-lin "></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <img src="proper_theme/images/properties/p7.jpg" alt="property"/>
        </div>
    </li>
```

my skeleton in the php function:

```
return "
    <li>
        <div class=\"shad\">
            <div class=\"mask\">
                <div class=\"box-detail\">
                    <h3>$title</h3>
                    <div class=\"box-detail-item\">
                        <div class=\"item-price pull-left\">$price</div>
                        <a href=\"#\" class=\"item-lin \"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <img src=\"$img\" alt=\"property\"/>
        </div>
    </li>";
```

**And there is no error in the console.**

Comment: Nothing to do with PHP. Modified to reflect this.

Comment: Can we see the site's source code?

Comment: Can you check the console and share the error, if any and also check if the bootstrap files are loaded properly

Comment: Furthermore, your issue is centrally localized to the construction of the HTML elements, as well as the CSS that is associated with said elements.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy his question was to do with PHP, rewording it doesn't change that fact.  The appropriate response would have been to explain that PHP could not be responsible for this issue and that it must be a html/css/javascript issue.  Not just delete the specific point he thinks is the problem

Comment: My money's on broken HTML, probably as a result of bad quotes from too much `echo` in PHP

Comment: @JonTaylor Please see my comment above, as I'd addressed that fact.

Comment: Your comment doesn't help though.  Now people reading the post will not understand that he is using PHP to output the html and thus his incorrect use of it and it's output is probably the cause of his problems.  You removed the one part of the question which indirectly is causing his problems.

Comment: i'm editing now to add codes.

Comment: i didn't publish on any site. if anyone wants i can give my dynamic dns or ip address with pleasure. Ohgodwhy thanks for editing. @Phil what do you think can cause this kind of broke? missing </**> tag?

Comment: Could you please the **output** HTML code to jsFiddle?

Comment: Thanks to @Ohgodwhy people think it's javascript...

Comment: @AndrzejOśmiałowski I don't know how to use it

Comment: I never said anything about JavaScript. Your issue is with HTML and CSS as I stated above, get your facts straight. No one's going to debug this without a link to the URL of the site, or a jsFiddle to simulate the environment.

Comment: Just copy the output HTML to the HTML textarea and save it.

Comment: @AndrzejOśmiałowski links are added

Comment: Besides, there is no error on the console.

Comment: @MelihYıldız' You sure you've labelled those links correctly? The *broken one* looks right to me. The *proper one* appears to have an extra `<body>` element added via JavaScript

Comment: @Phil my bad. Editing.

Comment: There is also a header function that calling in every page. For example in the index.php: `<?php include_once("inc.php"); header(0); ?>`

Comment: Thanks, problem is solved.

Comment: Examples were added but seems like mods didn't see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. There was a css code added in the header:

```
<style type="text/css">
    *{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        float:left;
        border:0;
    }
</style>
```

I don't know why but this code causes bootstrap's js files to broke. (adding extra elements so that css labels doesn't work i think)